# Android - How to know if a TCP connection is still opened

Tags: android, sockets

I'm doing an application that will comunicate with a TCP server. I based my work on the following example http://myandroidsolutions.funcode.ro/2013/03/31/android-tcp-connection-enhanced/.

Right now I'm looking how to verify if there is a connection between Client and Server. The mBufferOut.checkError() only give an error after 2/3 tries. I need to know if my message was sent or not.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In network communications, you are never sure when (or if) the remote party received the message in full, in part, or at all.

If the connection is broken, then you know for certain that message was not received in full.

But if you need a timely confirmation, the server should send some confirmation message. Your application protocol needs to support this, though.

The same is valid to know if the connection is "up" or "down": TCP does not exchange any packets when idle, unless you activate keep-alive (which is not normally recommended). It may well happen that the party thinks it has a connection, only to send a message and then it fails (perhaps because a router was reset while the connection was idle).

Comment: How I know if message fails to send? I only need to know if the message was sent or not. Thank you

Comment: Sent *how far* on it's way towards the intended recipient?  Also, in a protocol intended to retry, how (which is to say, after how many tries) do you wish to subjectively define failure?

Comment: "How far", perfect :) that was my point. Low-level APIs like BSD Sockets return success when sent message fit in the sending buffer.

Comment: After I switch the server off I can send 3 messages using `mBufferOut.println(message);
mBufferOut.flush();` before mBufferOut.checkError() return true. I want that to return true on the first sent message after tcp server turned off. My project if you want to take a look https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6416035/TCPClient.zip

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem we need to look at the return value of `readLine()`. If it return `null` so our tcp connection was closed.